# CROSS APPLY WITH UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, udf

```
Create function  getbyID  ( @id int )
Returns table

as 
return( 
select * from Products where  

ProductID=@id+10)
```

Function above retruns all records of the Products where the product Id is grater than 10 .

When used with     CROSS APPLY as below

```
select o.* from [Order Details] o 
CROSS APPLY getbyID(o.ProductID) P
```

i get in the result some productID less than 10  which is not possible .

The example uses NORTWIND database sample available everywhere .

ORDER DETAILS table and PRODCUTS tables are linked by the ProductID

```
Select* from getbyID (1)  gives result below
```

[image]

When the UDF is called  (as above) result shows some productID < 10

[image]

Can you see where is the error  ?

Comment: It's perfectly possible for it to return `Order Details` rows which have a `ProductID` that is less than 10. What you've got here is something that won't return `Order Details` rows for products 68 - 77.

Comment: @Stephan what i want is firstly the UDF to return only productID >= 10 .  i checked it works fine .  But when combined with cross apply it returns some productID less than 10 .

Comment: @Damien   the code above should return same result as if you had an innder join for productID >= 10 . That is my goal

Comment: @JavaMain I think Donal's code might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Read you UDF again. It says "if you hand me an ID value of 1, return rows with an ID value of 11", which obviously works. You may just have your logic backwards (i.e. if you subtract 10 then it would say "if you hand me an ID value of 1, return rows with an ID value of -9", and those rows obviously don't exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your function to just return products where the ProductID is greater than 10, you should add this check to the where clause. For example:

```
Create function  getbyID  ( @id int )
Returns table
as 
return( 
select * from Products 
where  
ProductID=@id AND
ProductID > 10)
```

Comment: I think you might want to change the ">" to ">="

Comment: Why do you need to add productID >10 . Because productID value starts from 1 .

Comment: Your code is working . But i cant understand why mine does not work.

Comment: @JavaMain - as I said below your question, read you UDF again. What results do you expect it to return if `@id` is equal to 1? Are there any entries in the `Products` table with an `ID` of 11? Because that's what your query is looking for, in such a case.

Comment: Yes there is an entry  having productID = 11 .